# WP_customize Switch between Header image or colored header.

Tags: wordpress, themes, admin, panel

I can not manage to solve this. I am making custom Customize panel in my wordpress theme and I want for user to be able to switch between header backgrounds: image or color. I can put text box so user can type #ColorCode or url("ImageUrl").

But i want Image picker for easy usability there and when I do that always some attribute has priority.

I also tried with variables but didnt manage. Can someone help? ty

Comment: Why would the user have to choose between the two? They might want to upload a transparent png & have the background color behind it, so just use both ;)

Comment: @admcfajn How to do that? :D I am changing css background property but I want to be able to pick images from library and if I put url ("echo ..") then color codes are not working

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty, as I'm not sure what your code looks like... You could use a radio button to switch between the two options... what about (it's kinda ugly, but could work for you) `<div id="header" style="<?php if( isset($bg_color_var) ){echo"background-color:".$bg_color_var.";";}if( isset($bg_img_var) ){echo"background-image:url(".$bg_img_var.");";}))?>">` ... I don't know how the data is saving... The bg_image is probably an array containing the image meta, as well as the url, so you'd use something more like `$bg_img_var['url']` or `get_thumbnail($bg_img_var['id'])`

Comment: just pseudo-code btw, but hopefully that shows the idea.